# Comparar hora do sistema com hora definida em uma váriavel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço para comparar a hora do sistema com uma hora definida em uma variável no jQuery ou Javascript?

Comment: "hora do sistema" é do utilizador no Browser, ou no servidor? A variável tem informação de hora em que formato?

Comment: do utilizador do browser

Comment: E o que está na variável está em que formato? timestamp? ISO?

Comment: por exemplo - 14:50:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugestão:

```js
function compararHora(str) {
    str = str.split(':');
    var agora = new Date();
    var varData = new Date();
    ['setHours', 'setMinutes', 'setSeconds'].forEach(function(fn, i) {
        return varData[fn](str[i]);
    });
    if (agora == varData) return 0;
    else return agora > varData ? 1 : -1;
}



console.log(compararHora('05:50:00'));
console.log(compararHora('23:50:00'));
```

Partindo do formato que indicaste de `hh:mm:ss`, podes partir essa string pelo `:` e usar os métodos que o JavaScript nos dá para mudar a hora a uma data. Depois comparas se a hora é a mesma, "maior que" ou "menor que", e na função que sugiro retorna respetivamente `0`, `1` ou `-1`;

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado Sérgio!